# factorisation of polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

> Given that $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2u^2(1-uz)}$ , show that 
>   \begin{equation*}
> \dfrac{f(z_1)}{(z_1-z_2)(z_1-z_3)}+\dfrac{f(z_2)}{(z_2-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}+\dfrac{f(z_3)}{(z_3-z_2)(z_3-z_1)}=\dfrac{2}{(1-au)(1-bu)(1-cu)}
> \end{equation*}
>   where $a$,$b$,$c$ are any $z_i$

Given 
\begin{equation*}
(z_2-z_3)(1-uz_3)(1-uz_2)-(z_1-z_3)(1-uz_3)(1-uz_1)+(z_1-z_2)(1-uz_2)(1-uz_1) , 
\end{equation*}
is it possible to factorise to the form $u^2(z_1-z_2)(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_3)$ ?
Is there any method to expand such polynomial efficiently without expanding everything?

Comment: where did you get this?

Comment: If $z_1=z_2$, your target form will vanish, but your source form does not. So, it is impossible to factorise in the way you specify.